# Ocaml is not creating .o file

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, ocaml, cc

I'm new to ocaml and ubuntu and I'm trying to compile a very simple ocaml file following this tutorial : http://wiki.njh.eu/OCaml_and_SDL

The problem is that it's not compiling I have the following error and I don't understand what to do :

```
cc   testsdl_1.o   -o testsdl_1
cc: testsdl_1.o: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
cc: no input files
make: *** [testsdl_1] Erreur 1
```

Comment: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type cc -> In english? :P In addition makefiles are extremely obnoxious about not leaving a tab after the ':' symbol (assuming you have a newline after ':' and then the <tab>). Make sure you do and post us your code PROPERLY intended please since it may help us here.

Comment: In english : no file or folder of this type cc

Comment: The makefile code is exactly the one on the tutorial I mentionned.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the ':' symbol. Thanks for your help btw ;)

Comment: It's a good tutorial. P.S.: I meant that testsdl_1 cc:<you press enter here><now you press tab once here><add your own makefile rule><repeat> -> http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm if you still don't understand what I mean :p

Comment: Do you compile in windows or linux?

Comment: I compile in ubuntu. I finally worked but the problem was that I didn't understood something in the tutorial. I was doing "make ./test_sdl1" instead of just "make". This is the problem of being a noob, but thanks a lot for your help I'm going to learn how to create a makefile !

Comment: It's ok!I'm satisfied you found your answer to your solution. If you think I've helped somehow please vote up and/or mark my post as an answer! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains about the fact that `testsdl_1.o` does not exist, which means that it has not been generated. So, there has been an error somewhere *before* the lines you are quoted. You should provide more information if you want your problem to be solved (or provide a solution if you found one).